# How to scale out flink task managers

Tags: apache-flink

I wonder what is the best practice of scaling out flink task managers automatically

that if for example i'm running at aws and add a new task mgr at autoscalling group.

it will start to execute jobs (i.e.) discovered by the job mgr

Thanks

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail of what you mean by scaling out automatically and with discovery of the job manager?

Comment: i mean that if for example i'm running at aws and add a new task mgr at autoscalling group. it will start to execute jobs (i.e.) discovered by the job mgr